# How to find matching row based on a condition and return N row above or below?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use Python Data Frames to process some NBA data.

I have a data frame of game events and I'm trying to find when an event matches a condition (shot is a 3pointer). I then want to look at the next event in the data frame, if this event matches another condition, I would like to return the next few rows.

I know this is not how to use data frames, but my first inkling is to loop and retain the values as variables.

I have tried using shift to do the first part, which is getting the matching event, and in row it will have the next event. Im not sure how to get n amount of rows after when i find the correct event (in this case its same team rebound)

I will chuck my current code in below, its really just trying to test the above.

Thanks

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url_base = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/playbyplayv2?EndPeriod=10&EndRange=55800&GameID=0022000049&RangeType=2&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0'

headers = {
    'Host': 'stats.nba.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
    "x-nba-stats-origin": "stats",
    "x-nba-stats-token": "true",
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.get(url_base, headers=headers)
content = json.loads(response.content)

results = content["resultSets"][0]
column_names = results['headers']
rows = results['rowSet']
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.columns = column_names

# get a new df with just these columns
main_df = df[['GAME_ID', 'EVENTNUM', 'HOMEDESCRIPTION', 'VISITORDESCRIPTION', 'PLAYER1_ID', 'PLAYER1_TEAM_NICKNAME']]
main_df['rebounder_team'] = main_df.PLAYER1_TEAM_NICKNAME.shift(-1)
# append the homedescription and player 1 team
main_df['shifted_home'] = main_df.HOMEDESCRIPTION.shift(-1)

# filter and make a new df for all home descriptions that have 3pts
home_df = main_df[main_df['HOMEDESCRIPTION'].str.contains('3PT', na=False)]

# find all rebounds that are the same team as the shooter
home_slice = home_df['PLAYER1_TEAM_NICKNAME'] == home_df['rebounder_team']

final_home = home_df[home_slice]

print(final_home.to_string())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this does the job. It chooses the subsequent indexes leaving off from the 3 PT ones, and then chooses all the rows in main_df with those index numbers.

```
final_home = home_df[home_slice]  
print(final_home.to_string())  # starting from where you left off

subsequent_rows = 3 # note it'll choose this value - 1, so pick 3 if you want 2

# returns a list of tuples that contain the ranges of indices following the initial event
index_ranges = home_df[home_df['PLAYER1_TEAM_NICKNAME'] == home_df['rebounder_team']].index.map(lambda x: range(x, x + subsequent_rows))
index_list=[]
# flatten the list of tuples to a list of all the index values we want
[index_list.extend(x) for x in index_ranges]
# go back to main_df and select all the rows with those index values
final = main_df[main_df.index.isin(index_list)]
print(final)
```

Comment: Hi there, yea this does work. Is using indexes like this a good option in terms of best practice for dataframes? Thanks for the answer, appreciate it

Comment: I don't see why not.  We're not changing the index or anything like that, just choosing more rows based on their indexes.